# Falla conexión SSH - Permission denied (publickey, password)

Tags: apache, ubuntu, servidor, ssh

Quiero establecer una conexión SSH para actualizar mi sitio web desde otra máquina, pero no lo consigo. Busco ayuda para interpretar el mensaje de la consola y sugerencias para corregirlo.

He estado siguiendo las instrucciones de [este tutorial](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SSH/OpenSSH/Keys):

- Instalé `SSH` y `OpenSSH`.
- Creé un par de claves `RSA` con el generador de SSH: `ssh-keygen -t rsa`
- Transferí la clave pública al host y la incluí en un archivo llamado
  `authorized_keys`
- Seguí las mismas indicaciones del tutorial para
  configurar `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` Reinicé el servicio SSH
- Traté de conectarme al servidor via SSH con `root@host`
- Sin embargo, siempre obtengo el mensaje que me solicita la clave de mi usuario, y aun cuando la ingreso correctamente, recibo un mensaje de error.
- Probé ver los bugs en la consola `ssh -v root@host`

Este es el mensaje que recibo:

```
OpenSSH_7.2p2 Ubuntu-4ubuntu2.2, OpenSSL 1.0.2g  1 Mar 2016
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to host [host] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: permanently_set_uid: 0/0
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_rsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.2p2 Ubuntu-4ubuntu2.2
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version 
OpenSSH_7.2p2 Ubuntu-4ubuntu2.2
debug1: match: OpenSSH_7.2p2 Ubuntu-4ubuntu2.2 pat OpenSSH* compat 
0x04000000
debug1: Authenticating to host:22 as 'root'
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: algorithm: curve25519-sha256@libssh.org
debug1: kex: host key algorithm: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256
debug1: kex: server->client cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: 
<implicit> compression: none
debug1: kex: client->server cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: 
<implicit> compression: none
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256 
SHA256: [host key]
debug1: Host 'host' is known and matches the ECDSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /root/.ssh/known_hosts:1
debug1: rekey after 134217728 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: rekey after 134217728 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: SSH2_MSG_EXT_INFO received
debug1: kex_input_ext_info: server-sig-algs=<rsa-sha2-256,rsa-sha2-512>
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering RSA public key: username@machine
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
debug1: Trying private key: /root/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Trying private key: /root/.ssh/id_dsa
debug1: Trying private key: /root/.ssh/id_ecdsa
debug1: Trying private key: /root/.ssh/id_ed25519
debug1: Next authentication method: password
root@host's password: 
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
Permission denied, please try again.
root@host's password: 
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
Permission denied, please try again.
root@host's password: 
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
debug1: No more authentication methods to try.
Permission denied (publickey,password).
```

No puedo descifrar el mensaje.

¿Alguna idea sobre cuál es el problema y qué puedo hacer para conectarme via SSH al servidor?

**NOTAS:** 
 - Aunque preferiría utilizar un usuario distinto al root, ese es el
   único que parece tener los permisos de escritura.
 - Creo que podría editar `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` para conectarme con mi clave de usuario y me ahorraría ese lío, pero usar pares de claves es más seguro.

**Actualización:**

Usando el comando  `ls -l ~/.ssh/id_rsa`

Obtengo el siguiente resultado:

```
-rw------- 1 root root 1766 ago 16 10:30 /root/.ssh/id_rsa
```

Comment: Abre una terminal y escribe este comando: `ls -l ~/.ssh/id_rsa` y actualiza tu pregunta con el resultado, usa este enlace: [edit].